# Unable to start hierarchyviewer

Tags: android

I'm trying to view the hierarchy of my views from my android application. So I read about hierarchyviewer and I installed it `sudo apt-get install androidsdk-hierarchyviewer`

The problem is that when I type in the terminal hierarchyviwer I got the following error :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/window/ApplicationWindow
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

I'm running Linux Mint version 17.1 x64. What thing should I check or what should I do in order to be able to start hierarchyviewer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `hierarchyviewer` inside the your Android SDK under the tools directory.

Comment: I know. That's the location from where I start it. But it can't be started because I got that error.

Comment: You don't need to install it. can you write the output of `which hierarchyviewer` ?

Comment: /usr/bin/hierarchyviewer. But I start it from opt/android-sdk/tools/hierarchyviewer and It give me that errors.

Comment: What about that command `./opt/android-sdk/tools/hierarchyviewer`?

Comment: That command gives me that error : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/window/ApplicationWindow` I ended up running `./monitor` who has a tab for the hierarchyviewer.